# Reason for putting this question on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

I was a bit surprised when I saw [How do I display user information from table 1 and 2 that don't exist in table 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838670/mysql-query-cant-figure-it-out#26838670) question on hold.

As I see, this question gives a clear database design, the need is clear, the effort is there....

**More importantly,** I think whoever reads the question, it is clear for him what was ask.

> How can I display user information from table 1 and 2 AS LONG as they ARE NOT already registered in table 3?

So what was **unclear** about this part?

Comment: The initial revision of the question (before it was closed, then edited) contained *I know what I want in terms of the query, just don't know what the best way or even how to create the query. Any help would be really appreciated.* "what the best way or even how to create the query" may have been deemed vague enough to warrant closure.

Comment: i have a comment there before any edit has happened. quoting these same above words. the edit op did was, noly he turned it into italics.

Comment: Your comment there was quoting the words in your question, not the ones in my comment here. Those have been removed from the question during the edit (which was a good move IMHO). They were detracting from the question even though the part you quoted arguably made it clearer.

Comment: isn't it better, before using mod priviledge to hold a question, just ask, what exactly he wants? (though it was there, but even if it was missed.... seeing the approach, asking for a clarity would have been greater approach, isn't it?)

Comment: Maybe. Though I highly doubt the moderator was acting in their name only here -- a flag was probably involved. In this situation, I have seldom seen a moderator requesting clarification, they usually close the question and let the poster edit it to clarify it. Given the number of flags they have to process, doing more than that would not possibly scale.

Comment: The title was really, really bad. And it appears that the attempted query was edited (given the "Edit:" mark in the first revision) - that should have been there from the start.

Comment: @Mat that is not my question.

Comment: The last line in http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26838670/1

Comment: but a _psudocode_ (almost a complete sql) was there. he was just trying to find out the last part of the construct.

Answer (score 4):

I just gave that question an edit  (and Mat fixed the stuff I missed, */me bad*) to improve its readibility and gave it a much better title. And I voted to re-open

From [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26838670/timeline) we learn that Andrew Barber close voted the question a minute after it was posted, his vote is binding. He probably did due to the useless title, the missing of information what currently works, or what errors pop-up with that query.

I admit it is not the worst question we see on a daily basis but it still is not a great one.

A final question to you: Why didn't you edit the question yourself and instead decided to post a question on meta?

Comment: because to me, the question made sense. as it did to _Raphaël Althaus_ i didn't see the point of editing it.